# Images flicker on post issue

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am working on social application and it's about to complete but I got stuck on one issue that is image flickering. When there is around 9 to 10 images on screen and if I scroll the page then the image flicker take place.

```
 @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.view_explore_icon, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.back = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_grid_album);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                Static_Urls.explore_logo_pic + categoryList.get(position).cat_logo,
                holder.img);

        if (pos == position) {
            holder.back.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.explore_selected_image);
        } else {
            holder.back.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.explore_blank_image);
        }
        holder.img.setTag(position);
        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pos = (int) view.getTag();
                txt_cat_name.setText(categoryList.get(position).category);
                //notifyDataSetChanged();
                new GetAllExplorePic().execute(categoryList.get(position).id);

            }

        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

displace the below lines of code inside of if(convertview == null)

```
holder.back = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
    holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_grid_album);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
```

your final code

```
    @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.view_explore_icon, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.back = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_grid_album);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

      //  holder.back = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
     //   holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_grid_album);
      //  convertView.setTag(holder);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                Static_Urls.explore_logo_pic + categoryList.get(position).cat_logo,
                holder.img);

        if (pos == position) {
            holder.back.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.explore_selected_image);
        } else {
            holder.back.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.explore_blank_image);
        }
        holder.img.setTag(position);
        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pos = (int) view.getTag();
                txt_cat_name.setText(categoryList.get(position).category);
                //notifyDataSetChanged();
                new GetAllExplorePic().execute(categoryList.get(position).id);

            }

        });

        return convertView;
    }
```